# Double dual of locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of finite rank

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

This question has been asked by many people and the answers are mostly suggesting verifying the isomorphism on stalks. But I really have no idea how to proceed:
we define $\alpha:\mathcal{E} \to (\mathcal{E}^\vee)^\vee$ by
$$\alpha_U:\mathcal{E}(U)\to(\mathcal{E}^\vee)^\vee(U)=Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X|_U}(\mathscr{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{E},U)|_U,\mathcal{O}_X|_U)$$
which sends $s\in \mathcal{E}(U)$ to $f_s:\mathscr{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{O}_X)|_U\to \mathcal{O}_X|_U$ where for $V\subseteq U$ any open subset, we have
$$f_s(V):Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X|_V}(\mathcal{E}|_V,\mathcal{O}_X|_V)\to \mathcal{O}_X(V)$$
sending an $\mathcal{O}_V$-module morphism $\varphi:\mathcal{E}|_V\to \mathcal{O}_V$ to $\varphi(s|_V)$.
Then I get lost in verifying the isomorphism on stalks. Now we want to show that, for any $p\in X$, we have isomorphism on the stalks
$$\alpha_p:\mathcal{E}_p\to ((\mathcal{E}^\vee)^\vee)_p$$
Assume we have $s_p,t_p\in \mathcal{E}_p$ such that $\alpha_p(s_p)=\alpha_p(t_p)$. Then since the trivialization $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $\mathcal{E}$ covers $X$, we may pick representatives of $s_p,t_p$ from some $\mathcal{E}(U)$ ($U=U_i$ for some $i$). And I am not sure what to do next. Maybe we need to use $\mathcal{E}_U\cong \oplus^n \mathcal{O}_X|_U$ and $\mathcal{E}_p\cong (\mathcal{E}|_U)_p\cong \oplus^n \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$?
Even thought I know that a finite module is isomorphic to its double dual in a natural way. I am not sure what to do next. This is a really stupid question. Thank you for any help!

Comment: One way to get an isomorphism on stalks is to first pass to fibers, note that this is a well-known canonical isomorphism of vector spaces, and then use Nakayama to lift the isomorphism from a point to a neighborhood (ie. to the stalks). I suppose just using the corresponding fact for modules is more elegant, but if you like thinking about actual vector bundles this way might be preferable.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you for the new approach. But I have not reached the vector bundle exercise in the book. I will try to check it when I get there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's totally normal to be confused by this; it's definitely no stupid question:P

You *are* supposed to use that the stalk $\mathcal{E}_p$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}^{\oplus n}$ (when dealing with vector bundles this is the main item in your toolkit). Then by means of the commutative diagram $$
   \require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{E}_p @>{\alpha_p}>> (\mathcal{E^{\vee \vee}})_p\\
@V{\cong}VV @VV{\cong}V \\
\mathcal{O}_{X,p}^{\oplus n} @>{\alpha_p'}>> (\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\vee \vee})_p
\end{CD}
$$ the morphism $$
   \alpha_p : \mathcal{E}_p \to (\mathcal{E}^{\vee \vee})_p
$$ (where $\alpha'$ is defined just as $\alpha$ but with $\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\oplus n}$ instead of $\mathcal{E}$) identifies with (by [TAG 01CP](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01CP)) the evaluation map $$
   \mathcal{O}_{X,p}^{\oplus n} \to \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}((\mathcal{O}_{X,p}^{\oplus n})^{\vee},\mathcal{O}_{X,p})
$$ which is an isomorphism, since as you mentioned for finite free modules over an arbitrary ring the evaluation map is an isomorphism.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thank you very much :) The conditions like "sheaf of finite type" mentioned in stacksproject is new to me. I am not sure but I have not seen it in Hartshorne. I think here we are able to apply the Lemma, since the sheaf is locally free of finite rank (so is its dual sheaf) hence, is finitely presented?

Comment: My pleasure:D that is correct! Finite type here just means the stalks are finitely generated modules, which is of course the case (indeed, in this case where the stalks are actually free modules, the lemma I referenced from the stacks project is particularly direct, because of the universal property free modules satisfy).